# Differentiate null from undefined on Symfony PHP

Tags: php, symfony

For example, I have the following entity Street:

- id: 1
- name: Street name
- house number: 1
- house number addition (nullable): 'A'

And the following graphql mutation:

```
mutation updateStreet ($input: UpdateStreet!) {
   updateStreet(input: $input) {
        id
        name
        houseNumber
        houseNumberAddition
   }
}
```

And the input:

```
{
    "input": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Changed Name",
    }
}
```

The problem is with the nullable field ("houseNumberAddition") because it will also be changed to null even if I don't want that.

The question is how can I differentiate between 'null' and 'undefined' in Symfony PHP ?

This is the command:

```
#[GQL\Input('UpdatePartner')]
final class UpdatePartner
{
    
    #[GQL\Field(type: 'Guid!')]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message: 'Partner guid is required')]
    #[Assert\Uuid(message: 'Partner guid is not a valid UUID')]
    public Uuid $guid;

    #[GQL\Field(type: 'String')]
    public ?string $street;

    #[GQL\Field(type: 'String')]
    #[
        Assert\Length(
            max: 255,
            maxMessage: 'House number exceeds limit of 255 characters'
        )
    ]
    public ?string $houseNumber;

    #[GQL\Field(type: 'String')]
    #[
        Assert\Length(
            max: 255,
            maxMessage: 'House number addition exceeds limit of 255 characters'
        )
    ]
    public ?string $houseNumberAddition;

    public function guid(): Guid
    {
        return Guid::fromString($this->guid->toRfc4122());
    }
}
```

Comment: `undefined` is a JavaScript type and does not exist in PHP.

Comment: Ok then, so how can you handle the situation presented?

Comment: If you want to distinguish a nonexistent key from a key whose value is null, use `array_key_exists()`.

Comment: Otherwise you could set `mixed $houseNumberAddition = false`. If `null` is passed in the mutation it overrides `false`. If `$houseNumberAddition` is false, no value was passed.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore type like this

```
#[GQL\Field(type: '?String')] OR [GQL\Field(type: 'null|String')]
#[
   Assert\Length(
      max: 255,
      maxMessage: 'House number addition exceeds limit of 255 characters'
   )
 ]
public ?string $houseNumberAddition;
```